# Areal interpolation with mostly missing data in R

Tags: r, polygon, interpolation, sf

I am attempting to preform an areal interpolation using R with the `sf` package's `st_interpolate_aw`.

Of note, my sampling scheme for my areal units is such that I have many missing values. When using the `st_interpolate_aw`, I am only returned missing values. Ideally, I am looking for predicted values based on these missing data. See the reprex below:

```
library(sf)
library(tmap)
url="https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2018/shp/cb_2018_us_zcta510_500k.zip"
tdir=tempdir()
if(file.exists(paste(tdir,"/cb_2018_us_zcta510_500k.shp",sep=""))==F){
  download.file(url,destfile = file.path(tdir,"ZCTAs.zip"))
  unzip(file.path(tdir,"ZCTAs.zip"),exdir=tdir)}
ZCTAs=read_sf(paste(tdir,"/cb_2018_us_zcta510_500k.shp",sep=""))
df1 = data.frame(val=seq(1:33144))
df1$val[c(501:33144)]=NA
ZCTAs=cbind(ZCTAs,df1)

g = st_make_grid(ZCTAs, n = c(50,50))
test=st_interpolate_aw(ZCTAs["val"], g, extensive = FALSE)
tm_shape(test)+tm_fill(col="val")
```

Is there a better way to make areal level predictions with many missing values using R?

Comment: When any of the "new" areas (in `g`) overlaps with `NA`, then the interpolated value is also going to be `NA`. What kind of different behavior would like to achieve?

Comment: @MichaelDorman I see. I’m trying to achieve something similar to a kriging interpolation. I’ve looked into ATA Poisson kriging, but the software isn’t readily available.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! Not familiar with Kriging thechniques where the measured data are in polygons rather than points. In any case, I guess you need to provide a specific example with real data, because the feasibility and choice of an interpolation method will depend on the distribution of measured data and their spatial pattern.

Comment: This seems relevant:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/atakrig/index.html

Comment: @MichaelDorman Wow thank you. I can't believe I couldn't find this in my search. The gstat package doesn't have ATA kriging as an option.